# algorithm puzzle about arangement pipe in channels

Tags: algorithm, graph, pipe

[image]

Just like the picture,i have some pipes with specifically path,and channels with known width,now i am writing a algorithm to arrange the location of the pipes in the channel,so they will not intersect with other pipes.i work on this puzzle for weeks,but still have a lot of problems.
Anyone known is there some similar algorithms? tell me the name ,thanks very much!!!

Comment: Genetic algo should work fine for you

Comment: really?Let me check out.Thanks!

Comment: each chromosome can be a matrix of pipes and channels, the fitness function can be calculated upon how good the solution is.

Comment: thanks very much. Can I ask is the Genetic algo efficiency ? Because I have a lot of channels and pipes,maybe 1000 channels and 10000pipes.

Comment: this will depend on your application of the algorithm, how you are forming the chromosome, and how you are calculating the fitness

Comment: ok,I will try this algo.Thanks!